# creating an instance for class TreeClass for datatype of an expression

Tags: haskell, recursion

If I have a dataytype Expr

```
data Expr = ExprNum Double -- constants
          | ExprVar String -- variables
          | ExprAdd Expr Expr
          | ExprSub Expr Expr
          | ExprNeg Expr -- The unary '-' operator
          | ExprMul Expr Expr
          | ExprDiv Expr Expr
          deriving Show
```

I have created a class TreeClass where
                  subTrees :: t -> [t]

I created an instance of the class for the datatype MTree
     data MTree a = MTree a [MTree a]
             deriving Show

```
instance TreeClass (MTree a) where
subtrees (MTree _ ss) = ss

singleton a = MTree a []
```

Now I wish to do The same for Expr datatype .I have expressions like 
the equation for ex1 is ex1 = y + x * 11 / 100
this has to be made into a tree and calculate the height and various parameters like number of nodes,leafs etc.

```
ex1 = ExprAdd (ExprVar "y")(ExprMul (ExprVar "x")(ExprDiv (ExprNum 11) (ExprNum 100)))
```

The expression is a Tree.
I tried to write the subTree function for Expr datatype as follows

```
instance TreeClass Expr where
subtrees a  = a
```

to calculate the height of the tree 
height function is written as

```
height :: (TreeClass t) => t -> Int
height t = 1 + foldl (\x y -> max x (height y)) 0 (subtrees t)

numNodes :: (TreeClass t) => t -> Int
numNodes t = 1 + foldl (\x y -> x + numNodes y) 0 (subtrees t)

leafs :: (TreeClass t) => t -> [t]
leafs t = case subtrees t of
  [] -> [t]
  st -> foldl (\x y -> x ++ leafs y) [] st
```

But while executing it on ghci (height ex1) its entering an infinite loop.
I know I am going wrong in writing subTree Expression for Expr datatype.

How do I execute height ex1?

Answer (score 2):

You're saying that `a` is a subtree of itself, so `height` ends up in an infinite loop when it tries to calculate the height of the subtrees.

You need to write subtrees by case analysis on the different constructors of `Expr`. For example, the case for `ExprAdd` would be:

```
subtrees (ExprAdd e1 e2) = [e1, e2]
```

Comment: I tried this way but its saying non- Exhaustive patter.It is not getting any terminating condition.

Comment: That line was just an example, you need to add a separate line for each constructor of `Expr`.

Comment: subtrees (ExprMul a b)  = [a,b]
     subtrees (ExprAdd a b)  = [a,b]
     subtrees (ExprDiv a b)  =[a,b]
     subtrees (ExprSub a b)  = [a,b]                                              I got that..and I did this and even for ExprVar and ExprNum

Comment: Remember to include cases for the constructors that don't have any subtrees either, e.g. `subtrees (ExprVar _) = []`. If you look at the "non-exhaustive pattern" error it'll tell you what you've omitted.

Comment: The error is  Non-exhaustive patterns in function subtrees

Comment: If that doesn't tell you the problem then try compiling with `-Wall` and check the compiler warnings.

Comment: @anujuhi01 please mark the answer accordingly so the question is shown as *solved*